# WordPress - add_filter vs apply_filters vs add_action vs do_action

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

**What are the difference between [`add_filter`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter), [`apply_filters`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters), [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) and [`do_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action)?**

I can see that `do_action` puts a tag in the code which can then be used by `add_action`. However, I can't see how `add_filter` and `apply_filters` correlate with this. One would think that there would be a `do_filter` which would add a tag to the code, much like `do_action`; but neither of these seem to do this. And neither of them have a simple form like `do_action( $tag )`, but instead require callback functions as parameters.

Comment: @danyll Nice editing. thanks for cleaning that up ... it was very messy. I think it was my first SO post or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters in wordpress are used to modify text. So, for instance:

Stripping SQL statements from a block of text before putting it in the database to avoid injection attacks. That would be a filter.

Actions are functions that are called when wordpress does something.  For instance, (from docs), emailing someone when a post is written.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: thanks - yes i knew that .... i was confused about the specific functions themselves and the naming conventions .... i've since discovered that add action is to do action what apply filters is to do filters